# Alternative to Nemenyi posthoc test that can use variance

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, friedman-test

I am applying statistical tests from paper "Statistical Comparisons of Classifiers over Multiple Data Sets" J. Demsar ([link](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/demsar06a/demsar06a.pdf)) in my own work. However, variance is pretty important, since different classifiers that I am comparing vary wildly in this regard.

Is there any alternative to Friedman-Nemenyi posthoc test that can take variance into consideration? Basically, has anything changed for section 3.2.3 of that paper since 2006?